# Node Js and ternary operators how to apply embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i just got some code for my discord bot from github and i want to make embedded message for it.

I have something like this:

```
const checkStatus = (data) =>

  data.online
    ? `IT WORKS` 
    : "NOT WORKING";
```

And i want it to be like:

If value is '?'

send simple embed like

```
// at the top of your file
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// inside a command, event listener, etc.
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('ITS WORKINGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG')
    .setURL('        ')
    .setAuthor('        ')
    .setDescription('        ')
    .setThumbnail('        ')
    .addFields(
        { name: '        ', value: '        ' },
    )
    .addField('        ', '        ', true)
    .setImage('        ')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('        ');

channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

(Spaces are example text here)

And when value is ':'
send other embed but with title 'NOT WORKING'

Can someone just do it for me ? please without laughing...

Comment: Please go read [ask], among other things, it explains what a proper question title should be phrased like. The current one here sounds as if you simply listed several “keywords”, making the title very redundant to what you already _tagged_ this question with.

Comment: So you _just_ want to change the title of what you are sending, everything else is supposed to stay exactly the same? (You also say “different embed”, so that is rather confusing here.) If so - well then “apply” the ternary inside of `.setTitle(…)`, where exactly is the problem with that? `.setTitle( foo ? 'bar' : 'baz' )`

Comment: I want to send full embed like it is, not only title but only in titlles write if something is working or not

Comment: So do it as I said then.

Comment: I dont have idea how can i implement full embed into this
```
const checkStatus = (data) =>

  data.online
    ? `IT WORKS` 
    : "NOT WORKING";
```

Comment: Can you please do it for me ? i beg you

Comment: You can do the research. [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: _“I dont have idea how can i implement full embed into this”_ - who said you should do that? If you want to send the same embed, only with a different title (that is what I _think_ you want to do here, and I explicitly asked you for clarification of that, but I don’t think you actually understood) - then use the ternary in exactly that place, where you specify the title - and that is the `.setTitle(…)` line.

Comment: What about rest of embed like footer and others i want them too

Comment: @KamilSkwirut I'm sorry, but your question is unclear. Please edit your post and ask a precise, concise coding question that can easily be answered. As of now, I personally have no idea of what you're trying to achieve. If it's just a problem with your understanding of ternaries, check out the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit

I feel like I haven't answered the question correctly. Actually, I'm not really sure what the question is. You should check out @CBroe's comment, it looks like it's what you're looking for.

#### Original answer

Conditions are pretty much the basics of programming. Ternary operators are only used to produce nice code, but it's sometimes harder to read.

To check if `data.online` is `?`, in a ternary operator, it would simply be:

```js
data.online === "?" ? "works" : "fails"
```

Or, with an else clause, in a much more unreadable way:

```js
data.online === "?" ? "works" : data.online === ":" ? "fails" : "neither"
```

My advice would be to let the ternaries alone and get back to standard `if-else` clauses. You could also try [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statements, they seem pretty relevant here.

```js
let embed;
switch (data.online) {
  case "?":
    embed = "Your success embed"
    break;
  case ":":
    embed = "Your failure embed"
    break;
  default:
    // If it doesn't match the previous conditions
}
someChannel.send(embed)
```

Comment: switch (data.online) {
^

ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/bot/bot.js:21:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Comment: Thats what im looking for but how to implement embed like in my question  in here
  case "?":
    embed = "Your success embed"  <<<<Here
    break;

Comment: Do you know how to debug? Elementary coding skills are important before starting a project, and pooping an error stack in a SO comment doesn't really help. This says that your `data` object doesn't exist.

Comment: You simply need to define the var with a new embed. Replace my strings with `new Discord.MessageEmbed().stuff` or something like that.

Comment: For me its not that simple XD

so yeah if my question was not that easy to understand maybe ill try to explain it a bit here:

https://pastebin.com/yRG94CCA

Comment: You move `new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor('#0099ff').etc` after `embed = `. I can't help more than that.

Comment: If you send me example how its done i would love that

Comment: Where is `data` defined?

Comment: Here's full code https://github.com/skykanin/MC-Status-Discord-Bot

Comment: data.online is defined in api i think

Comment: You think? You should know what your code does or represents, otherwise how will we be able to help

Comment: Its not my code... it takes data from mcsrvstats  api